# Is there something wrong with my OBJ file reader?

Tags: file, format, wavefront

I had implemented code that read .obj files for my Ray-Tracer, construct a bunch of triangles and send it to be rendered by a ray-tracer.

And it works........for the first kind of .obj files that I tried.
For instance, with files that presented. lines like these:

> f 3437 3438 3400 3419

things seems to be fine.

now with files that uses lines like these:

> f -107/-138/-105 -116/-149/-114 -119/-156/-121 -112/-143/-110

it is rendering things like these (it should be a car):

[image: image.jpg]

Then I started to check if the builded triangles made any sense. For instance for the line:

> f -107/-138/-105 -116/-149/-114 -119/-156/-121 -112/-143/-110

It will first create a triangle using the vertices 107,138,105
Then it will create another using the vertices 107,105,116
then another one using vertices 138,116 and 149.
So, except for the first triangle, it will always pick a vertice x, the vertice x+2 and the vertice x+3.
It will proceed on this way until it the last triangle is construct.

Is there anything wrong with this procedure? It worked wit the first files.

I know the program is also using the correct vertices because I created a duplicated .obj file from where I took the line:

> f -107/-138/-105 -116/-149/-114 -119/-156/-121 -112/-143/-110

and at every vertice line like

> v  -4.3773 9.1046 33.4049       107

as can be seen, I noted the line number so to make easier to see if the vertices chosen by the triangle construction algorithm were correct. And they are.

So the the triangle building seems to be correct according to an algorithm that I read here in an old post, and seems to be the choice of the correct lines from the file where the vertices are read.

So what else can be the cause. It is possible that one shall build the triangles according with these subgroups ?

triangle 1

> 107/-138/-105

triangle 2

> -116/-149/-114

....

There is not a single line in the file where there is not a multiple of 3 vertices.

Comment: Take a look at the [wavefront obj file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). You aren't reading the file properly. The `/` character has a very special meaning. The format you are seeing is: `vertex / texture index / normal index`. You should only care about the first part.

Comment: Furthermore, negative indices are supposed to specify an offset from the end of the respective list with `-1` specifying the last element.

Comment: Thnaks to both for the help.